# finding asm instruction in compiled C program

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86

I have very simple C program:

```
int foobar(int a)
{
    int b = a;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    foobar(0xDEAD);
    return 0;
}
```

Using `objdump -d main.out` I got disassembled binary with a lot of assembler instructions:

```
  4004a3:   55                      push   %ebp
  4004a4:   48 89 e5                mov    %esp,%ebp
  4004a7:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%esp
```

How can I find for example address of every `push` instruction from another C program? 
Can it be done this way?:

```
position = 0;
while (...)
{
   ...
   int act_value;
   read(binary_file, &act_value, 4);

   if (act_value == /*what value?*/)
   {
      printf("Instruction: push\n");
      printf("Address: %X\n", position * 4); /* is this correct?*/
   }
   position++;
   ...
}
```

Comment: You can't do it that way.  x86 instructions are variable length (as you can observe in your disassembler output); not all bytes correspond to opcodes.

Comment: Oli Charlesworth is correct. You'll actually have to parse the executable to differentiate between an actual `push` and a coincidental sequence of bytes. Furthermore, executables can rewrite themselves at run time, so you won't necessarily get all the instructions this way. It may be easier to delegate the task of disassembly to an external program like `objdump` rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: `objdump -d binary|grep push`

Comment: @drhirsch Was my answer too wordy? :)

Comment: @AndersSjöqvist I didn't read it :-) Yes, and way to much words ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Oli Charlesworth already pointed out, instructions are of variable length on the x86 architecture. You can still write a program to do this for you, but you'll need to parse all the instructions to properly know how long they are and where the next one starts.

I don't understand why you want to write your own program to solve the problem, or is there something you're not telling us? Are you only looking for a way to find the addresses of the `push` instructions? If so, just do this:

```
objdump -d another_c_program | grep push
```

Of course, this will also find `pushl` and so on. I guess you want them too, otherwise the command can be modified.